# Error: Cannot find plugin.xml for plugin "phonegap-plugin-push". Please try adding it again

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, ionic2, phonegap-pushplugin

I am trying to add the phonegap-push-plugin as described in the [doc](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/INSTALLATION.md#installation-requirements).

I found this [thread](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/775) listing the problem but with no solution given.

As explain in the doc, I did a CLI in [My project folder]: `ionic plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --variable SENDER_ID="[project id from Google Developper Console]"`

At firts I had issue with Cordova and Cordova-android version. I updated Cordova from 6.3.0 to 6.4.0 and then did a CLI: `ionic platform rm android` to remove the existing version 5.2 Cordova-android project.

After that when I do a `ionic info` I get:

- **Cordova CLI: 6.4.0**
- Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.0
- Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.0
- Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.0-beta.1
- OS:
- Node Version: v6.7.0

And if I do a `ionic platform ls` I get:
Available platforms:

- amazon-fireos ~3.6.3 (deprecated)
- **android ~6.0.0**
- blackberry10 ~3.8.0
- browser ~4.1.0
- firefoxos ~3.6.3
- webos ~3.7.0
- windows ~4.4.0
- wp8 ~3.8.2 (deprecated)

Now the only problem left when I launch `ionic plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --variable SENDER_ID="[project id from Google Developper Console]"`  is this message:

> Error: Cannot find plugin.xml for plugin "phonegap-plugin-push".
>   Please try adding it again.

Any idea?

Comment: You might try using a slightly earlier version of the plugin -- maybe the latest version is broken. You can specify version numbers using `@x.y.z` after the plugin name.

Comment: thanks I finaly managed it by using full url instead of plugin name. And it is the last version.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've finally managed it by switching plugin name (phonegap-plugin-push) by full URL (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push):

`ionic plugin add https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push --variable SENDER_ID="[project id from Google Developper Console]`

instead of:

`ionic plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --variable SENDER_ID="[project id from Google Developper Console]`

Comment: I have faced this issue many times and always use the full url method.Don't know why?

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution. If you get an error "Cannot find plugin.xml for plugin" try to install a plugin like this ionic cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push

Answer (score 9):

I experienced a similar error albeit when trying to add the storage plugin:

```
Error: Cannot find plugin.xml for plugin "cordova-sqlite-storage". Please try adding it again.
```

I found out that the plugin folder somehow still existed in myapp/plugins such that I had a myapp/plugins/cordova-sqlite-storage

I deleted  `myapp/plugins/cordova-sqlite-storage` plugin directory and added the plugin afresh and it was successful.

Answer (score 0):

If you get an error "Cannot find plugin.xml for plugin" try to install a plugin like this ionic cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push